# Replace relative path backslashes in C# .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, relative-path

I'm trying to get a specific format of the output of the relative path between two paths like so:

```cs
var from = @"C:\This\is\my\path\folder1";
var to = @"C:\This\is\my\path\folder2\folder3";

var relativePath = System.IO.Path.GetRelativePath(from, to);

System.Console.WriteLine(relativePath);
// output --> ..\folder2\folder3
// desired output --> ../folder2/folder3/
```

It's important that there is also the trailing `/` because in the end i need the output as a subtitution string for another string.

Is there another way to get the desired output without manipulating the string, like a framework function or something?

Or is this the only solution?

```cs
var desiredOutput = $"{relativePath.Replace('\\', '/')}/";

System.Console.WriteLine(desiredOutput );
// output --> ../folder2/folder3/
```

Comment: You normally don't need to care about `/` vs \ because Windows works with either.

Comment: *Why* do you want to replace the backslash? As for the trailing slash, use `Path.Combine` or `Path.Join` to combine the path you created with another instead of concatenating strings

Comment: Perhaps an even better solution would be to use `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` objects instead of concatenating strings

Answer (score 2):

Seems fine to replace the DirectorySeperatorChar.
A litte bit more robust would be the usage of what System.IO already offers.

```
  var from = @"C:\This\is\my\path\folder1";
  var to = @"C:\This\is\my\path\folder2\folder3";

  var relativePath = Path.GetRelativePath(from, to);
  relativePath = relativePath.Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar);

  System.Console.WriteLine(relativePath);
```